# Do correleated subqueries work like a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm learning Training Kit Exam 70 461 and the next query is not understood:

```
SELECT 
     categoryid
     ,productid
     ,productname
     ,unitprice
FROM Production.Products AS P1
WHERE 
     unitprice =
         (SELECT MIN(unitprice)
         FROM Production.Products AS P2
         WHERE P2.categoryid = P1.categoryid);
```

How does this work?

if I won't have the **WHERE clause** then i will get 1 result as followed:

```
 SELECT 
      categoryid
      ,productid
      ,productname
      ,unitprice
 FROM Production.Products AS P1
 WHERE unitprice =
      (SELECT MIN(unitprice)
      FROM Production.Products AS P2);
```

and then

```
categoryid productid productname unitprice
----------- ---------- -------------- ----------
   4          33    Product ASTMN  2.50
```

but when the first query is executed then I get:

```
categoryid productid productname unitprice
----------- ---------- -------------- ----------
1             24    Product QOGNU   4.50
2             3     Product IMEHJ   10.00
3             19     Product XKXDO  9.20
4             33     Product ASTMN  2.50
5             52     Product QSRXF  7.00
6             54     Product QAQRL  7.45
7             74     Product BKAZJ  10.00
8             13     Product POXFU  6.00
```

I don't get it.
How does this work?
is it like a loop inside a loop?
**categoryid 1** which is the outer query and then loop inner query to get **categoryid 1**? 8 times up to **categoryid 8**?

I cannot proceed without understanding this.
I'm working with **SQL Server** with **Northwind** as the book followes.

Comment: Provide sample data also...

Comment: If you want to understand how a query works, then you need to learn about execution plans.  A good place to start is by generating them in SSMS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Are you asking about logically or physically? If physically that is optimizer dependent. SQL is declarative. A correlated sub query may or may not run as nested loops. The example you give may use the segment top pattern. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Correlated Subquery is a sub-query that uses values from the outer query.

See example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Correlated subquery is an inner query referenced by main query (outer query) such that inner query considered as being executed repeatedly.

Co-Related Vs Nested-SubQueries.

Technical difference between Normal Sub-query and Co-related sub-query are:

1. **Looping**: Co-related sub-query loop under main-query; whereas nested not; therefore co-related sub-query executes on each iteration of main query. Whereas in case of Nested-query; subquery executes first then outer query executes next. Hence, the maximum no. of executes are NXM for correlated subquery and N+M for subquery.
2. **Dependency(Inner to Outer vs Outer to Inner)**: In the case of co-related subquery, inner query depends on outer query for processing whereas in normal sub-query, Outer query depends on inner query.

3.**Performance**: Using Co-related sub-query performance decreases, since, it performs NXM iterations instead of N+M iterations. ¨ Co-related Sub-query Execution.

For more information with examples :

http://dotnetauthorities.blogspot.in/2013/12/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Training-Online-Learning-Classes-Sql-Sub-Queries-Nested-Co-related.html

Answer (score 0):

In your first query,

```
SELECT categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
FROM Production.Products AS P1
WHERE unitprice =
(SELECT MIN(unitprice)
FROM Production.Products AS P2
WHERE P2.categoryid = P1.categoryid);
```

query,

```
SELECT MIN(unitprice)
FROM Production.Products AS P2
WHERE P2.categoryid = P1.categoryid
```

selects minimum price for `each` category in  `products` table. to it will return all the `records` in the products table & unit price will be the `minimum` price for each row.

In your second query,

```
 SELECT categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
 FROM Production.Products AS P1
 WHERE unitprice =
 (SELECT MIN(unitprice)
 FROM Production.Products AS P2)
```

query

```
SELECT MIN(unitprice)
 FROM Production.Products AS P2
```

returns a single value. in your case it was `2.50`
i.e

your query become

```
 SELECT categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
 FROM Production.Products AS P1
 WHERE unitprice = 2.50
```

so it will return single row alone. Hope it clear now